# How to convert a point on screen into indices of the corresponding object in a 2d-array

Tags: java, arrays, swing

I have a 2d-array of Rectangle-objects which make up a grid in JPanel. I want to make a method which will take x and y coordinates of a MouseEvent as parameters and return the indices of the corresponding Rectangle in that array. Let's say every Rectangle in that array has the area of 30x30 pixels and we have a point at x = 36, y = 15. The result in this case should be indexX = 1 and indexY = 0. All I need is a formula which would calculate it.

Edit: I made a simplified version of my problem:

```java
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;

public class Grid extends JPanel {
    private final Rectangle[][] grid = new Rectangle[10][10];

    public Grid() {
        this.setSize(300, 300);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
                grid[i][j] = new Rectangle(i * getWidth() / 10, j * getHeight() / 10, 30, 30);
            }
        }
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
                g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                g.fillRect((int) grid[i][j].getX(), (int) grid[i][j].getY(), (int) grid[i][j].getWidth(), (int) grid[i][j].getHeight());
            }
        }


    }

    public static Point mousePositionToRectangleIndex(int xPos, int yPos) {
        //Problem:
        //int indexX = formulaHere;
        //int indexY = formulaHere;
        // return new Point(indexX, indexY);
        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        Grid grid = new Grid();
        MouseMotionListener mml = new MouseMotionListener() {
            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                mousePositionToRectangleIndex(e.getX(), e.getY());
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {

            }
        };
        frame.addMouseMotionListener(mml);
        frame.add(grid);
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

All I need is the formula for mousePositionToRectangleIndex()

Comment: The formula will depend on the dimensions of the component and the grid.  Please show real [mre] code if possible.

Comment: Better still, fill the JPanel with a grid of JLabel using a GridLayout, and give the JLabels a MouseListener.

Comment: But for your example, int remainder (`%`) and int division (`/`) will be all you need.

Comment: The problem is that I can't use JLabel cause each Rectangle should be a representation of a "pixel" and should change its color after a certain MouseEvent. I had a solution in which i iterated through the entire array to check if given point is within a rectangle, but I want to optimize it by getting the indices directly through calculation.

Comment: *"The problem is that I can't use JLabel cause each Rectangle should be a representation of a "pixel" and should change its color after a certain MouseEvent."* -- this hardly rules out use of a JLabel. The representation of the rectangle is all about your program's underlying model and has nothing to do with what you choose to represent it with. Separate your concerns.

Comment: As far as "optimization" that also doesn't make sense since these issues have little to do with program bottleneck.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I probably didn't make myself clear enough, so I made a short code representation of my problem. mousePositionToRectangleIndex() should return a Point with the indices of the Rectangle-object in "grid"-array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply check which rectangle has been pressed in your mouse listener to find out your i and j. For example:

1. give the grid JPanel a preferred size, not a size:

```
    public Grid() {
        // this.setSize(300, 300);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
                grid[i][j] = new Rectangle((i * getPreferredSize().width) / 10, (j * getPreferredSize().height) / 10, 30, 30);
            }
        }
        
        addMouseListener(new MyMouse());
    }
```

2. give it a MouseListener that checks if a rectangle contains the click point:

```
    private class MyMouse extends MouseAdapter {
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            for (int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < grid[i].length; j++) {
                    if (grid[i][j].contains(e.getPoint())) {
                        System.out.printf("Point pressed, i, j: [%d, %d]%n", i, j);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

3. Don't set the JFrame's size (you're forgetting the menu bar takes space, but rather pack it:

```
        frame.add(grid);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        // frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
```

For example:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;

public class Grid extends JPanel {
    private final Rectangle[][] grid = new Rectangle[10][10];

    public Grid() {
        // this.setSize(300, 300);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
                grid[i][j] = new Rectangle((i * getPreferredSize().width) / 10, (j * getPreferredSize().height) / 10, 30, 30);
            }
        }
        
        addMouseListener(new MyMouse());
    }
    
    private class MyMouse extends MouseAdapter {
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            for (int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < grid[i].length; j++) {
                    if (grid[i][j].contains(e.getPoint())) {
                        System.out.printf("Point pressed, i, j: [%d, %d]%n", i, j);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
                g2.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                // g.fillRect((int) grid[i][j].getX(), (int) grid[i][j].getY(), (int) grid[i][j].getWidth(), (int) grid[i][j].getHeight());
                g2.fill(grid[i][j]);
            }
        }


    }

    public static Point mousePositionToRectangleIndex(int xPos, int yPos) {
        //Problem:
        //int indexX = formulaHere;
        //int indexY = formulaHere;
        // return new Point(indexX, indexY);
        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        Grid grid = new Grid();
        MouseMotionListener mml = new MouseMotionListener() {
            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
                mousePositionToRectangleIndex(e.getX(), e.getY());
            }

            @Override
            public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {

            }
        };
        // frame.addMouseMotionListener(mml);
        frame.add(grid);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        // frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

But having said that, the whole thing can be done with a JLabel grid, and perhaps a little more cleanly too. Here I increment the color of the clicked cell:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Grid2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            GridPanel mainPanel = new GridPanel();

            JFrame frame = new JFrame("GUI");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.add(mainPanel);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }

}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class GridPanel extends JPanel {
    private static final int SIDES = 10;
    private static final int MAX_COLORS = 6;
    private static final Dimension LABEL_SIZE = new Dimension(30, 30);
    private int[][] model = new int[SIDES][SIDES];
    private JLabel[][] labelGrid = new JLabel[SIDES][SIDES];
    private List<Color> colors = new ArrayList<>();
    
    public GridPanel() {
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_COLORS; i++) {
            float hue = ((float) i) / MAX_COLORS;
            Color c = Color.getHSBColor(hue, 1f, 1f);
            colors.add(c);
        }
        setLayout(new GridLayout(SIDES, SIDES));
        for (int i = 0; i < labelGrid.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < labelGrid[i].length; j++) {
                model[i][j] = 0;
                JLabel label = new JLabel();
                label.setPreferredSize(LABEL_SIZE);
                label.setOpaque(true);
                label.setBackground(colors.get(0));
                label.addMouseListener(new MyMouse(i, j));
                labelGrid[i][j] = label;
                add(label);
            }
        }
    }
    
    private class MyMouse extends MouseAdapter {
        private int i;
        private int j;
        
        public MyMouse(int i, int j) {
            this.i = i;
            this.j = j;
        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            System.out.printf("Point pressed, i, j: [%d, %d]%n", i, j);
            model[i][j]++;
            model[i][j] %= MAX_COLORS;
            labelGrid[i][j].setBackground(colors.get(model[i][j]));
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: I've already had a similar solution with for-loops, but wouldn't it get slow when the grid would get bigger? I also chose mouseDragged-Event cause I want to modify multiple rectangles by dragging my mouse over them. So with mouseDragged, there would be huge amounts of iterations by moving the mouse fast. I'm wondering if there is a solution that would calculate the needed indices of that certain rectangle instead of looping through the entire array every time the event gets triggered.

Comment: @ErnestPW: no, it would remain quite responsive. I think that you're worrying about the wrong issues, to be honest.